Docker container consuming all CPU por fastAPI Python script
I have a couple of Docker images, with a database and a REST API fastAPI using Python. When I run all images using docker compose (or even each container separately using docker run, the fastAPI container command takes all the CPU and makes the machine slow. See image:

However, running the same python command it takes almost no resources.

Here the command on the Dockerfile:
CMD ZMQ_NETWORK="ai_manager" uvicorn api_rest.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --env-file database/config/docker.env
And here the Python command when I run as a python script directly:
python3 -m uvicorn api_rest.main:app --reload --env-file database/config/local.env
Of course the env file is different but that is only usernames and passwords and ports.
Why do I have this huge difference when running a container fastAPI?
The Dockerfile uses FROM ubuntu and only does apt-get for pip, some pip installs (like obvously fastapi[all] and COPY of my python files. There is nothing else.
It is also weird that the docker container command appears twice.

Solved, the problem was with the --reload command. Removing it solved the issue.
